# How to iterate Single<List<Item>>, then perform a task based on a condition?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a method that returns a `Single<List<Item>>`, the only way to iterate over the list is to `flattenAsObservable()`:

```
getListOfItems()
    .flattenAsObservable {items -> items}
    .flatMapSingle { item ->
       doSomethingWith(item)
    }
```

In `doSomethingWith(item)`, I update an `item` object in the database.

Now, I want to "count" the updated items in the database, if they are N, perform another update.

I'm looking for something like:

```
getListOfItems()
    .flattenAsObservable { items -> items }
    .flatMapSingle { item ->
       doSomethingWith(item)
    }
    .flatMapSingle { items -> items } // I can't access items here, obviously.
                                      // I think I need another call to
                                      // getListOfItems() and then filter(),
                                      // but don't know how to do that.

    .filter{ items.size() == X }
    .flatMapSingle {
       doSomething()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the original items tag along and build a fresh list again. Note, however, that you havent defined the datatypes to those `doSomethingWith` so I assume they return some `Single` value.

```
getListOfItems()
.flattenAsObservable { items -> items }
.flatMapSingle { item ->
   doSomethingWith(item).map { item }
}
.toList()
.flatMap {
   if (it.size() == N) {
      doSomething()
   } else {
      Single.just(it); // make it return something with the same type as doSomething()
   }
}
```